# Prove $e^x \geq 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \cdots + \frac{x^n}{n!} $ for all odd $n$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality, taylor-expansion

If $x \geq 0$, the result is trivial. But when $x < 0$, we can see
$$
    e^x  - \sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!} = \sum_{k = n + 1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k|x|^k}{k!} 
$$
may be negative. I do not know how $n$ is odd will make it nonnegative.

Comment: Do you know the Lagrange remainder formula?

Comment: One only needs integration to address this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is $\theta\in[0,1]$, for which  $$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+...+\frac{x^n}{n!}+\frac{e^{\theta x}}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}.$$

Comment: Elaborate please. Why does that $\theta$ exist?

Comment: This is the "Lagrange remainder formula", an exact expression for the error in approximating a function by one of its Taylor polynomials (a generalization of the mean value theorem).

Comment: Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Since $\exp$ is convex, we have $e^x \ge 1+x$, or equivalently
$e^x-(1+x) \ge 0$, for all $x$.

We need only deal with $x<0$.

Note that if $g_0(x) \ge 0$ for all $x \le 0$, then $g_1(x)=\int_0^x g_0(y)dy \le 0$ for all $x \le 0$, and similarly, $g_2(x)=\int_0^x g_1(y)dy \ge 0$ for all $x \le 0$.

Suppose $n$ is odd and the formula is true for all $x$.
Write the formula as
$e^x-(1+x+\cdots) \ge 0$.

Integrating twice over $\int_0^x$ (for $x<0$) shows that the formula holds for $n+2$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Thank you so much!